# Pyinstaller - failed to execute script: why?

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

```
Fatal Error Detected: Failed to execute script main
```

I used the following tags:

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py
```

I had dependencies, so when it finished, I moved the exe file to the main directory. I'm still getting an error. I used pygame for my project. Why?

Comment: We need a sample code in main.py to reproduce the error! Have you tried it with a simple `print("Hello World!")`?

Comment: Need to see the libraries' in main.py and other dependencies. Also pls share the full error trace log.

Comment: I used pygame, time, pickle, random, and 3 other python files. I put those files in a directory then in another directory in the same directory as my main file. The error was a FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.

Comment: Did you get the error when you closed the program? Or when you just opened it, before anything happened?

Comment: @D_00 A message box appeared as I try to run the exe. I used a --debug all tag, and the FileNotFoundError happened.

Comment: Dumb question: have you copied the other files in the `.exe` directory?

Comment: @D_00 They're in a folder in the root directory, but I referenced them inside main.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. It turns out, it had nothing to do with images. It had to do with the font. Normally, in PyCharm (maybe I'm mistaken) freesansbold.ttf is a default font. However, when PyInstaller packages the files, PyInstaller doesn't have the font downloaded by default, so it gives an error. All I had to do was scour the internet for the font, downloaded it, and it worked.

So yeah, pretty funny mistake.

Answer (score 0):

When you are converting a `.py` file into `.exe`, PyInstaller shows the console. If there is an error in your code, it will be displayed in the command prompt.

But if you are converting a `.pyw` file into `.exe`, the error will be returned in the form of a message box instead.

So, to see your error (it is really quick though, but it is better than nothing), simply convert your file **in `.py` format** into an `.exe`, to see the error in the command prompt.

---

But when no window has been open, if there is an error at the beginning of the script, PyInstaller will not detect it as launched, so it will not show an error.

for example this program works, even if there is an error in the code:

```
avkzebhrkjvzebverybvzkejhrv
```